# UsedRange in excel column

Tags: c#, excel, interop

How do you get a column from the UsedRange; for example column A?

```
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\base.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

//range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A") // reading from A1 to max of excel 65536?
```

Comment: Please, Please, Please don't make more answers when you need more input for your question.  That's what comments are for on Stack Overflow.  If you want to take the null entries out of the range object after you have acquired it, then please ask another question.  Don't add more questions on to your specific question.

Comment: I'll flag the moderator to change your answers to comments.

Comment: Those answers need to be edits to the question.  They're too long to be comments.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you Column A, which as Joe points out might be the first column in your UsedRange:

```
range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns["A:A", Type.Missing]
```

This will get you the first Column in your range, so you can reference by number:

```
range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns[1, Type.Missing]
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote happened, but if you want verification that this works, then see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411355/how-do-i-get-an-entire-column-in-used-range/5411554#5411554).

Answer (score 2):

@Lance's answer:

```
range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns["A:A", Type.Missing]
```

will give you the first column of UsedRange.  If, for example, the first column that contains data is column C, it will actually return the used part of column C.

To get the used rows of the first column in the worksheet, use Intersect:

```
range = xlApplication.Intersect(xlWorksheet.UsedRange, xlWorksheet.Columns["A:A", Type.Missing])
```

This will return null if column A is not part of the UsedRange.