# How to get cell index and number of rows using the column name in C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

So I have a method that is passing in a sheet name and column name and I am trying to get the cell index and number of rows in that column based on that column name. I am not sure where to start this is my method

```
public static int GetColumnIndex(Excel.Worksheet worksheet, string columnName)
{

}
```

Comment: Is column name defined in the first row of the column ?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333202/how-do-i-get-an-excel-range-using-row-and-column-numbers-in-vsto-c) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411355/how-do-i-get-an-entire-column-in-used-range)

Comment: @Micah Armantrout yes it is lets say its Application ID