# C# Interop get last row with data from a specific column

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm trying to get the last row with data from a specific column and I'm getting the following error when running my code:

> Unable to get the CountA property of the WorksheetFunction class

```
var xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
var wb = (Excel.Workbook)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
var wsConfig = wb.Sheets["Config"];

var usedRows = xlApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsConfig.Columns[9]);
```

Also tried the following code, but returns:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

```
var usedRows = wsConfig.Range["I1", wsConfig.Cells[1, wsConfig.Rows.Count]].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Value;
```

Example:

Column I
|  1  |
|  2  |
|  3  |
|  4  |
|  5  |
|     |

=> `usedRows = 5` because there are 5 rows with data on the column I

Comment: The error message just means you passed the `CountA` function an incorrect argument. I believe it expects a valid `Excel.Range`. If it's the ninth column I think it should be `wsConfig.Columns("I:I")` that you pass to `CountA` but I'm guessing as I don't have a project to hand.

Comment: Oh, I think if you look here the accepted answer might be what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411355/how-do-i-get-an-entire-column-in-used-range

Comment: I tried that but it returns 51 (total number of rows).

Comment: Maybe it also counts the cells whose background color is different?

Comment: `CountA` won't get the last row if there are empty cells *between* other cells in the column you are looking at. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Comment: @RobinMackenzie there won't be empty cells between other cells in the column. I checked that question I and think that the code from "Find Last Row in a Column" could help me, but I don't know how to convert VB to C#...

Comment: I think the code you posted in your edit is on the correct track. Try: `var usedRows = wsConfig.Range["I" + wsConfig.Rows.Count].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;` And maybe you will need to cast `wsConfig.Rows.Count.ToString()`

Comment: Tried it, and I get `usedRows = 1048576`

Comment: With `xlUp` not `xlDown` ?

Comment: Sorry, I used `xlDown` ... it works after changing it to `xlUp`! You should post the solution as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: No problem - I posted an answer. Feel free to accept if it helped !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) method to get the last used row in a column (e.g. `A`) is:

```
last = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Which says 'working from the last available row in the worksheet (changes from version to version) go upwards until you hit a cell with a value - your last row.

You can write this in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) in your example (for column `I`) with:

```
var usedRows = wsConfig.Range["I" + wsConfig.Rows.Count.ToString()].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a couple of years old but just thought I'd put this here. The accepted answer may require a bit of tweaking, as it didn't quite work for me. So I've modified it to the following:

```
var usedRows = wsConfig.Range["I" + wsconfig.Rows.Count.ToString()].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp]
```