# C# and Excel, select column by name and get highest value

Tags: c#, excel

I'm quite new with c#, and with excel management too. I'm trying to do it with  `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.
I have an excel file of this kind:

[image]

and what i want to do is open the file, read a column (i.e. x-com column) and get the highest number (in case of numbers, of course).

I opened the file with

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets[sheetNumber];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
```

`fileName` and `sheetNumber` are the inputs of this method.

- how can i read only one column? and get the highest number?
- [optional] I am not sure what exactly is an Excel.Range. how can I print it on the console? what would look like the print if I print `xlRange`?

Comment: A bit of research on Google would find you quite a bit of information - the very top item when search for "Excel interop select column" gives you this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411355/how-do-i-get-an-entire-column-in-used-range  Further results will show how to access individual cells. It should be noted that the Cells property is a  COM object which is accessed like a standard array - but unlike (most) C# arrays the start offset is 1 NOT 0.

Comment: My comment about the start offset of the Cells property also applies to Range

Comment: You might want to consider connecting using ADO.NET, or preferably using a library such as [ExcelDataReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader), which avoids the overhead of opening the Excel application and manipulating its objects.

Comment: Int max_value = xlapp.WorksheetFunction.Max( xlWorksheet.Range("C:C") )

Answer (score 2):

Edit: 
I used the following libraryes:
 - `using ExcelDataReader;`
 - `using ClosedXML.Excel;`
I don't really remember wich of the two libraryes I used but It probably is the second one.

You can try this code:

```
var file = new XLWorkbook("YOUR EXCEL FILE PATH");
           var foglio = file.Worksheet("sheet"); //select the worksheet
var firstRowUsed = foglio.FirstRowUsed(); //Gets the first row used
var ComuniRow = firstRowUsed.RowUsed(); //Gets the very first row used (in your case A1:"Control System")
var LastRow = LastRowUsed.RowUsed(); //Last Row used
ComuniRow = ComuniRow.RowBelow();//Select the row below (in your case A2:"P/M").
string Value = ComuniRow.GetString(); //Assigns "P/M" to the string
```

Now you have the exact position of a field.
At this point you just have to cycle the whole column till the "LastRowUsed".

```
while(ComuniRow != LastRow)
{
    string test = ComuniRow.GetString();//the value of the current selected cell
    ComuniRow = ComuniRow.RowBelow();
}
```

If you need to select a specific Column you can use `.Cell(x)`

```
while(ComuniRow.Cell([cell value]) != LastRow.Cell([cell value]))
{
    string test = ComuniRow.Cell([cell value]).GetString();//the value of the current selected cell
    ComuniRow = ComuniRow.RowBelow();
}
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning which library you are using as this is not Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: @PaulF You're right... sadly I don't remember I'll add the library as soon as I can haha

Comment: @PaulF I added the libraryes :)